# How to handle Android permission Dialogues using Appium C#

Tags: c#, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Appium with C# client.

When launching an Android app, I get several permission dialogue boxes like this one.

[image: Android Screenshot]

I would like to click on "Allow" or "Deny" buttons, which I am unable to do using below code.

```
var Allow_Btn = driver.FindElementById("permission_allow_button");
Allow_Btn.Click();
```

After a lot of googling, I found out that we can skip these permissions by using the below capability.

```
Capability.SetCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
```

But I would like to know if there is any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by Xpath locators only. Find by id would not worked for permission dialog handling.
To find "ALLOW" button you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]") //it denotes "Allow" button
```

and for "DENY" button you,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][1]") //it denotes "Deny" button
```

Before you click the button you should wait until the element located

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);                
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Mohanraj for your reply.
Could you please try on this app at apkpure.com/raaga/net.amp.raaga/download?from=details.
Let me know if it works for you as none of the below techniques work for me.

driver.FindElement(new ByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"ALLOW\")")).Click();   driver.FindElementById("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button");
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]").Click();

Comment: @Abhi3106 I used it in my application and worked as expected and fine.

Comment: Would you mind giving a try on that app and share your results. It would be helpful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where did you get this `permission_allow_button` ID, I don't think the locator is correct.

Here is how it looks like for me in [Android Device Monitor application](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)

[image]

So if you still want to use the [strategy of finding the element by ID](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/) - you should use `com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button` ID.

Another option is going for [XPath selectors](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+XPath+Feature) like:

- `//Button[@text()='ALLOW]`
- `//Button[@resource-id='com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button']`

Comment: I usually use the ID that way and it works every time.

Below is the app that I am using to test.

https://apkpure.com/raaga/net.amp.raaga/download?from=details

Below techniques didn't work.

  driver.FindElement(new ByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"ALLOW\")")).Click();            
 driver.FindElementById("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button");
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]").Click();